# How to create class that inherits from TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want to make a custom TextBox class that inherits TextBox
and overrides onKeyDown event to make Tab functionality when key Enter is pressed.

There is duplicates of this question but none of the answers I found make sense so I want to open a fresh discussion.

I don't want to Inherit from UserControl but from TextBox... is this really that hard to do? I can't seem to find straightfoward tutorial or example on how to do this.

Something like this:

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        this.KeyDown += customKeyDown;
    }

    void customKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I have very little experience with working with UserControls or CustomControls and it was long time ago so I forgot the key things

Comment: look up the override keyword and I think you will have what you need

Comment: Also: don't call it a UserControl (which is a container type). It will be a Customcontrol, ie a control's subclass

Comment: @SeanK In a single-line `TextBox` it will work even without overriding. But for a multi-line `TextBox` it will not work even with overriding.

Answer (score 4):

You just override `OnKeyDown` event handler, no need for `UserControl` here.

Class below moves to next control when ENTER key is pressed in single- or multiline textbox. When multiline, ENTER can be inserted by pressing SHIFT+ENTER.

As added bonus, annoying "ding" sound is suppressed (in simplest possible way which works well if you do not need to handle the key outside the control).

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && (!Multiline || Multiline && !e.Shift))
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                // Removes "ding" sound by NOT passing the key down to container
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```