# How to block function key's event (ENTER) in RichTextBox WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, richtextbox

In my Wondows Form I have one RichTextBox (multiline) element as a message window. When user press "Enter" it sends string-message with a text from this element. But it also makes a new line when Enter is pressed.
How can I block "new line" default event when function key Enter is pressed in RichTextBox? When user press Enter I need only 1 action "send message", not 2 actions.
**But!** if user press SHIFT+ENTER he can still make a new line as by default. That's the point.

But I can't find the place or command how to block Enter's default action with new line i have been searching for a long time. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create class that inherits from TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817975/how-to-create-class-that-inherits-from-textbox)

Comment: It looks close but the solution is harder to do for a newcomers. Here is a better variant. Anyway thanks for the link, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the KeyDown event, handle it appropriately and then let the RichTextbox control know it's been handled:

```
private void YourRichTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //Do what you have to do
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I understand it right that it would do my command first and then it would block default action for Enter? If it is so than how can I be sure that my own action will be done first? Is it possible that first of all it would make a new line, than my action and there would be nothing left to handle?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But still it will be nice if you would answer my previous comment :)

Comment: @wooden_coder: Hi there, sorry, just got out of a meeting. What this will do is fire when the user presses a key but before the actual handling of the event is done by the control and give you the ability to do whatever you want to do and optionally tell it if it should continue to process the key by setting `e.Handled = true;`.